# Convert CONST D3DMATRIX to XMMATRIX

Tags: directx-11, directx-9, directxmath

I'm programming a wrapper for first time and working with lots of different header files, but reached a problem.
I can't convert D3DMATRIX to XMMATRIX. Looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxmath/pg-xnamath-migration-d3dx it says how XMMATRIX needs to be 16bit aligned but D3DMATRIX doesn't have that requirement.

code:

```
XMMATRIX WVP1;
---
---
HRESULT m_IDirect3DDevice9Ex::SetTransform(D3DTRANSFORMSTATETYPE State, CONST D3DMATRIX *pMatrix)
{
    WVP1 = WVP1 * *pMatrix;

    ---
    ---
}
```

In this code, everytime SetTransform is called I want to times the matrix thats passed through with an existing matrix.

The calling function always passes through a D3DMATRIX I think so I cant change that. I also need to work with XMMATRIX type.

I've tried some code to sort this but it hasn't helped for example

```
const_cast<XMMATRIX*>(&WVP1) = const_cast<XMMATRIX*>(&WVP1) * reinterpret_cast<CONST XMMATRIX*>(pMatrix);
```

I don't know how to go about fixing this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `XMFLOAT4X4` which is the 'memory type' for a 4x4 float matrix and it has no alignment requirement. It has the same structure layout as `D3DMATRIX`.

```
XMMATRIX m2 = XMLoadFloat4x4(reinterpret_cast<const XMFLOAT4X4*>(pMatrix));

WVP1 = WVP1 * m2;
```

> Per the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxmath/ovw-xnamath-progguide) *Programming Guide*, `XMVECTOR` and `XMMATRIX` should in most cases be thought of as proxies for SIMD registers, not as data types. For example, if you have a class and you make `XMVECTOR` or `XMMATRIX` a member of that class, then the whole class has to be 16-byte aligned. While this is generally true for x64 native code, it is NOT true for x86 code.

> If you are new to DirectXMath, take a look at [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) in the *DirectX Tool Kit*.